# Create dynamic html table with Struts html taglib

Tags: java, html, struts

i want to create struts form "html:form" but input inside this form for example "html:select" need it to create dynamic ,i mean i will add button that will add other row  for that table which contains another struts html input.

Comment: you can do that with JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript:

HTML:

```
<table id="aTable">
    <tr><td>row 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>row 2</td></tr>
</table>
<button id="newrow">Add row</>​
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#newrow").click(function(){
    $('#aTable tr:last').after('<tr><td>row 3</td></tr>');
  } 
  );
});​
```

See that fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vzasC/ to run this example.